# Use Xpath to find XML nodes with a specific child element

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm new to the world of XPath. I'm wanting to take an XML approach to powering my simple portfolio website instead of a database, which in this case would be superfluous as the only database element would be the projects themselves.

I've authored an XML file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<projects>
    <project>
        <title>A-Merchandise</title>
        <slug>a-merchandise</slug>
        <projectType>E-commerce</projectType>
        <launchDate>2007-08-01</launchDate>
    </project>
    ...
```

Now, I can parse this XML file fine with PHP for a listing overview, but how do I go about filtering projects with XPath? For example, how do I obtain all `project` nodes that has a child `projectType` node with the value `e-commerce`?

Normally, I would run a SQL query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `category` = 'e-commerce';
```

What would the XPath equivalent be? Is my XML file in the right structure to accomodate this filtering?

Any pointers would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated to the question, but to your purpose, have you considered using sqlite ? The database engine is initialized in the same process space as the application and database files are stored in a "*.db" format. Sqlite has PHP-bindings and you can send SQL statements just as any other database engine. Check this link out:

Comment: @de costo - I love SQLite as much as the next guy, but completely off topic... How do you know he isn't using sqlite now?

Comment: @Byron - Suggested as option to the author's purpose of storing files. In my opinion, there should be no need to XML files ones you have .db files for storing information.

Comment: @de costa - you are right, I didn't realize he authored the xml file. I take my previous comment back!

Comment: Wow. Just want to say thanks to all of the helpful answers in such a short amount of time. Unfortunately I can only select one answer as correct, but there were more than one that were more than helpful to me. Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

considering your xml file name is foo.xml and is in same dir of bar.php which has content

```
$projects = simpleXMLElement('foo.xml',null,true);

$ecomProjects = $projects->xpath('project[projectType="E-commerce"]');

foreach($ecomProjects as $ecomProject)
{
echo $ecomProject; // or do whatever with it
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe you want this:

```
/projects/project[projectType="e-commerce"]
```

The `[]` filter selects all `project` elements under `projects` who have a `projectType` child with value `"e-commerce"`

I've also found [this site](http://ogres.sandre.eaufrance.fr/ops/sandbox-xpath/) to be very helpful for messing around with XPath and XSLT queries.

Further reading: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 2):

Bone up on xpath, it is very useful. Althought I don't like w3cshools in general, their [xpath docs](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) are pretty good.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query("/projects/project") as $node)
{
   if ($node->textContent == "e-commerce")
   {
    // this node is the one you want.
   }
}
```

or using pure xpath

```
  foreach ($xpath->query("/projects/project[projectType = 'e-commerce']") as $node)
  {
        // grab the $node
  }
```

Some pointers

To select a node anywhere in the doc prefix with double slashes i.e. `//nodeYouWant`. To select an attribute use  `@` i.e. `/nodeName[@attribute='attributeValue']` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath filers, like that:

```
//project[projectType='E-commerce']
```

In the documentation of XPath ( http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates ), there is this example:

> `chapter[title="Introduction"]`
>   selects the `chapter` children of the
>   context node that have one or more
>   `title` children with
>   [string-value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) equal to
>   `Introduction`

Comment: There is no need for starting `//` operator when the schema is wellknown.

Answer (score 0):

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) is a good place to start.

I would probably change projectType into an attribute of project and then select like this:

```
//project[@projectType ='e-commerce']
```